# How can I transfer data from NodeJS to Python script

Tags: python, node.js, child-process

I have to use Python script in my NodeJS project, but I don't quite understand how to send data from Node to Python. In the Internet I've found information about child_process. So, I want to send an object and then get message that it has been proceed.

NodeJS:

```
const {spawn} = require('child_process');
const process = spawn('python3', ['process.py']);

async function start() { 
  let data = [1,2,3,4,5];
  process.stdin.write(JSON.stringify(data));
  process.stdin.end();
}
```

Python:

```
import sys, json, numpy as np
def read_in():
    lines = sys.stdin.readlines()
    return json.loads(lines[0])

def main():
    lines = read_in() 
    print (lines)

if __name__ == '__main__': 
    main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass it in the array argument like this:

```
const process = spawn('python3', ['process.py', var1, var2]);
```

Comment: Thank you, but how can I use var1, var2 in python?

Comment: Add the following to your py script:
`import sys`

To access the variables passed to a py script, use sys.argv[] like this:
`myVar1 = sys.argv[1]`
`myVar2 = sys.argv[2]`

As you see, I use 1 and 2 instead of 0 and 1, because 0 will refer to the name of the script, while 1, 2, 3 and so on will be the arguments used when calling the script.